# Objc wait for REALM object is exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, realm

I have a function that run after application start, it retrieve the realm object with specified ID and display it.

The problem is sometime the app is requesting to get object from API or REALM is in write transaction. So the object is nil in that time.

The question is: How to create a thread that wait until REALM object is exists with specified ID?

Comment: Listen for a Results notification token that checks for items with that given ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use Realm notifications:

https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#notifications

```
// This should be a field in your class:
RLMNotificationToken *token;

.............

__weak <<YourClass>> *weakSelf = self; // Create a weak reference to self to avoid a retain cycle
self.token = [realm addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *notification, RLMRealm realm)
{
    <<YourClass>> *strongSelf = weakSelf; // Create a strong reference to self to make sure it's still there
    Product *product = [Product objectInRealm:realm forPrimaryKey:<<primaryKey>>];
    if (product != nil)
    {
        // The product is present, do some action
        [strongSelf.token invalidate]; // Stop listening for changes
    }
}];
```

---

I edited the source code with more details. Please note I've written this in the browser, so it's not tested and that I haven't used Objective-C in a long time (recently been coding in Swift only).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but are you sure it will works with non-existent object?

Comment: In this case the block will be called every time anything changes in the Realm (note that there is no reference to your specific object yet), so it’s just the matter of checking if the object is there inside the block.

Comment: What if I want it to stop notice?

Comment: And the question is for object with specified ID, please explain in more details and thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post your object’s class so I can include more specific implementation.

Comment: It could be Content or Product.

Comment: Actually I tried to use Notification Block and it's not working with non-existent objects.

Comment: Please post Content or Product source code and I will include more detailed implementation. Is “ID” the primary key?

Comment: Where is the `realm` object from?

Comment: The first one is your Realm instance (you can use the default one ofc), the second one is passed as parameter to the closure.